# AS3 draw dynamic intersection shape when both movie clips are collide each other

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have two existing movieclips, but now need help on how to create dynamic intersection shape(shading) when both movieclip are collide.

something like this [see the picture from this website - cyan or grey shape color]:
http://www.icoachmath.com/math_dictionary/intersection_of_sets.html

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [the blendMode property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BlendMode.html) of the flash.display.DisplayObject class.

To apply a blend mode to a movie clip instance by the code:

```
import flash.display.BlendMode;

myClip.blendMode = BlendMode.MULTIPLY; // blend mode of myClip
```

You can also use the Display menu in the Properties panel of myClip. You just have to select Blending: Multiply.

[image]

Comment: Thanks helloflash, but I still don't get it. I just need to know how to make the shading @ generate a shape of the intersection area dynamically, after both movieclips are intersects@collide each other :)

Comment: Thanks again @helloflash, yes! after tried a few times, now I've got it, these is a good and easiest way to do, so I managed to do it without any further progamming, just apply the magic [the blendMode property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BlendMode.html) :)